# Matching the contents only inside the selection group

Tags: regex

I am looking for a way to match some contents, which should exist only inside my selection group. Say, I have a string file like this :

```
module asdf (a,b,c,d,e);

input a;

input b;

output c;

output d;

output e;

assign c = a;

endmodule

module abc (p,q);

input p;

output q;

assign q = p + q ;

endmodule

module asdf (x,y);

input x;

output y;

assign y = x ^ y ;

endmodule

module xyz (l,m);

input l;

output m;

assign m = l - m;

endmodule
```

I want to match the contents of all output ports for the module asdf. These output ports can vary in number, but they follow the same syntax.

I am able to match the whole module asdf as below:

```regex
(module\s+asdf[\s\S]+?)(input\s+[\s\S]+?)(output\s+[\s\S]+?)endmodule
```

with this lazy match, along with output ports, I am also matching the assign statements in group-3.

Ideally, I want to match the whole module like:

```regex
(module\s+asdf[\s\S]+?endmodule)
```

now, in this group, I want to search further. I know that while writing a script, we can capture the contents of the whole module into one variable and then, in next step re-search with-in those contents. But, is there a way to search contents, with-in a captured group in a single shot?

Is there a way to search within the captured reg-ex group, in a single shot.

```regex
(module\s+asdf[\s\S]+?endmodule)
```

The expectation is to match:

```
output c;

output d;

output e;

output y;
```

Comment: Which tool or programming language do you use?

Comment: In language/script, it's not a problem. I want a way in the Vim editor. As I need to view the contents interactively for editing files manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If supported, you could make use of the `\G` anchor to assert the position at the end of the previous match and get your matches in the first capturing group:

```
(?:^module\s+asdf\b.*(?:\n+input.*)*\s+|\G)(output.*)\n+(?=(?:(?!(?:end)?module).*\n)*endmodule)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^module\s+asdf\b.*(?:\n+input.*)*\s+` Match from the start of the string the part from module asdf including the inputs
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(output.*)\n+` Capture in group 1 output until the end of the string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:(?!(?:end)?module).*\n)*endmodule` Match endmodule and make sure that in between the is no module at the start of the string
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8Acbv/1)

If `\K` is also supported, you could get the matches instead of the capturing groups:

```
(?:^module\s+asdf\b.*(?:\n+input.*)*\s+|\G)\Koutput.*\n+(?=(?:(?!(?:end)?module).*\n)*endmodule)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tas1Um/1/)